# How to make individual tableview cells disappear or change height = 0?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a tableview based on another tableview list. I want to make an individual cell disappear when it has no value inside of it (NOT FOOTER!). So far I have tried using the heightatRow function with conditionals but it is not working. How do I make the height = 0 if there is no text inside the cell OR is there another way I can make the cell disappear

This is the code I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var myTableViewTwo: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return(3)

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cellTwo = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cellTwo")
        cellTwo.textLabel?.text = foodA[indexPath.row]

         return(cellTwo)

    }

    private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if food1 == "\(Acerra) cups of Kale"
        {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }
    if food1 == ""
        {
            return 0

        }
    if food2 == "\(Acacia) cups of Quinoa"
        {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    if food2 == ""
        {
    return 0

        }
    if food3 == "\(Raeva) cups of Apple"
        {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        }
    if food3 == ""
            {
                return 0

            }

    else {
        return 45
            }

    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if list.contains("Kale")
        {
            let cupsKale = "\(Acerra) cups of Kale"
            food1 = String(cupsKale)


        if list.contains("Quinoa")
            {
                let cupsQuinoa = "\(Acacia) cups of Quinoa"
                food2 = String(cupsQuinoa)
            }


        if list.contains("Apple")
            {
                let cupsApple = "\(Raeva) cups of Apple"
                food3 = String(cupsApple)
            }

        }

    }

    func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image: List of Foods]

[image: Second List based on First]

I would like the space between "___ cups of Kale" and "____ cups of Apple" to disappear because the user did not select Quinoa. Yet it is leaving space for it! Any help is greatly appreciated! I am pretty new to swift.

Comment: Don't mean to be a jerk, but the solution may come with wiping your code and starting over. Use switches, use arrays, use boolean variables. Slightly more complex strategies will make your code much simpler.